# How to set default filter on page load in slickgrid

Tags: jquery, grid, slickgrid

I want to set default filter on page load in slickgrid.This are the below code
on calling slicgrid.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
LoadslickGrid();
});



 function LoadSlickGrid(txtHRMFilter) {
        $(function () {
            var data = [];

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetDetails/?strFilter=' + txtFilter,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    data = result.desc;

                }
            });

            // Need to use a DataView for the filter plugin
            //var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();

            grid = new Slick.Grid("#grid", dataView, columns, options);

            grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());





            dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                grid.updateRowCount();
                grid.render();
            });

            dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
                grid.render();
            });

            dataView.beginUpdate();
            dataView.setItems(data);
            dataView.setFilter(filter);
            dataView.endUpdate();

            var filterPlugin = new Ext.Plugins.HeaderFilter({sortAvailable: false});

            // This event is fired when a filter is selected
            filterPlugin.onFilterApplied.subscribe(function () {
                dataView.refresh();
                grid.resetActiveCell();

                // Excel like status bar at the bottom
                var status;

                if (dataView.getLength() === dataView.getItems().length) {
                    status = "";
                } else {
                    status = dataView.getLength() + ' OF ' + dataView.getItems().length + ' RECORDS FOUND';
                }
                $('#status-label').text(status);

            });
            var pager = new Slick.Controls.Pager(dataView, grid, $("#pager"));
            // Event fired when a menu option is selected
            filterPlugin.onCommand.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                dataView.fastSort(args.column.field, args.command === "sort-asc");
            });

            grid.registerPlugin(filterPlugin);

            var overlayPlugin = new Ext.Plugins.Overlays({});

            // Event fires when a range is selected
            overlayPlugin.onFillUpDown.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                var column = grid.getColumns()[args.range.fromCell];

                // Ensure the column is editable
                if (!column.editor) {
                    return;
                }

                // Find the initial value
                var value = dataView.getItem(args.range.fromRow)[column.field];

                dataView.beginUpdate();

                // Copy the value down
                for (var i = args.range.fromRow + 1; i <= args.range.toRow; i++) {
                    dataView.getItem(i)[column.field] = value;
                    grid.invalidateRow(i);
                }

                dataView.endUpdate();
                grid.render();
            });

            grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({ selectActiveRow: false }));
            grid.registerPlugin(checkboxSelector);

            grid.registerPlugin(overlayPlugin);


            grid.init();


            function filter(item) {

                var columns = grid.getColumns();
                var value = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                    var col = columns[i];
                    var filterValues = col.filterValues;
                    if (filterValues && filterValues.length > 0) {
                        value = value & _.contains(filterValues, item[col.field]);
                    }
                }
                return value;
            }


            $("#divLoading").fadeOut("fast");
            if (data.length == 0) {
                $("#divLoading").fadeOut("fast");
                $.ajax().done(function () { alert("No records found"); });
                $("#txtHRMFilter").val('');
            }

        });
    }
```

The filter are working fine but i want to show the default filter values on pageLoad

These are the column details

```
var columns = [];
    var columnFilters = {};
    columns.push(checkboxSelector.getColumnDefinition());
    columns[1] = { id: "id", name: "Id", field: "id", sortable: true, width: 103, formatter: docNoFormatter };
    columns[2] = { id: "FirstName", name: "First Name", field: "FirstName", sortable: true, width: 135, formatter: formatter };
    columns[3] = { id: "LastName", name: "Last Name", field: "LastName", sortable: true, width: 135, formatter: formatter };
    columns[4] = { id: "Flag", name: " Flag", field: "HighRiskFlag", sortable: true, width: 128, formatter: formatter };
    //columns[4] = { id: "Date", name: " Date", field: "JoiningDate", sortable: true, width: 125, formatter: formatter };
    columns[5] = { id: "Category", name: "Category", field: "Category", sortable: true, width: 250, formatter: formatter };
    columns[6] = { id: "Date", name: "Date", field: "RenewalDate", sortable: true, width: 125, formatter: formatter };
    columns[7] = { id: "State", name: "State", field: "State", sortable: true, width: 100, formatter: formatter };
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please set up a https://jsfiddle.net/ with sample JSON data and any external resources for slick grid.

Comment: Please provide few more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter function looks for values in the property named filterValues on each column. To place a filter on the grid set the filterValues property on the relevant column to an array containing all the filter values.

You can do this when you set up the columns before initialising the grid. The below snippet is an example of putting a filter on the values 'TEST1' and 'TEST2' onto the column named 'Category'.

```
columns[5] = { 
    id: "Category", 
    name: "Category", 
    field: "Category", 
    sortable: true, 
    width: 250, 
    formatter: formatter,
    filterValues: ['TEST1', 'TEST2']
};
```

Or you can programmatically add / remove filters by updating the relevant columns then refreshing the grid (and updating the status bar). The below snippet places a filter on the values 'TEST1' and 'TEST2' onto the column named 'Category'.

```
function applyAFilter(){
    //Retrieve the column for 'Category'
    var column = grid.getColumns()[grid.getColumnIndex("Category")];

    //Set the filterValues on this column to 'TEST1' and 'TEST2'
    column.filterValues = ['TEST1', 'TEST2'];

    //Alternatively clear the filterValues on this column
    //column.filterValues = [];

    //Ideally the below would be placed in a function and called from both the anonymous function subscribed to the filterPlugin.onFilterApplied event and here.
    dataView.refresh();
    grid.resetActiveCell();

    //Update status bar
    var status;

    if (dataView.getLength() === dataView.getItems().length) {
        status = "";
    } else {
        status = dataView.getLength() + ' OF ' + dataView.getItems().length + ' RECORDS FOUND';
    }
    $('#status-label').text(status);
}
```